# How to generate swagger.json

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using java spring boot framework to create REST api for my project and I am using "springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui" for generating swagger documentation. I am able to see my documentation using the URL http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html.

**How can I create or generate swagger.json / spec.json**, The documentation should not be with this application, we are using a separate application for listing the API docs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have done this with a small trick

I have added the following code in the end of my home controller test case

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;

public class HomeControllerTest extends .... ...... {

@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;


@Test
public void testHome() throws Exception {
     //.......
     //... my home controller test code 
     //.....

    String swagger = this.restTemplate.getForObject("/v2/api-docs", String.class);

    this.writeFile("spec.json", swagger );
}

public void writeFile(String fileName, String content) {

    File theDir = new File("swagger");

    if (!theDir.exists()) {
        try{
            theDir.mkdir();
        } 
        catch(SecurityException se){ }        
    }

    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter("swagger/"+fileName);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();
            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
}
```

I don't know this is right way or not But it is working :)

Dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 29):

You can get the url with your swagger-ui html page:

[image]

```
GET http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs?group=App
```

And actually you can get all the urls with chrome/firefox develop tools network feature.

Comment: How do you download the swagger.json / spec.json files from this url?

Comment: In browser type the complete  URL.. and you get JSON as response. Which can be cut and paste as json file

Comment: how can I do this using java?

Comment: Do you know whether the corresponding file is put into jar after the build? So that I don't have to start the app and download it...

Comment: @ka3ak so you can try the (swagger-maven-plugin)[https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin] which answered by MK-rou  in this question's answer list, you can refer to this answer.

Answer (score 14):

If you use Maven, you can generate client and server side documentation (yaml, json and html) by using [swagger-maven-plugin](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin)

Add this to your pom.xml:

```
.....
 <plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <apiSources>
            <apiSource>
                <springmvc>true</springmvc>
                <locations>com.yourcontrollers.package.v1</locations>
                <schemes>http,https</schemes>
                <host>localhost:8080</host>
                <basePath>/api-doc</basePath>
                <info>
                    <title>Your API name</title>
                    <version>v1</version>
                    <description> description of your API</description>
                    <termsOfService>
                        http://www.yourterms.com
                    </termsOfService>
                    <contact>
                        <email>your-email@email.com</email>
                        <name>Your Name</name>
                        <url>http://www.contact-url.com</url>
                    </contact>
                    <license>
                        <url>http://www.licence-url.com</url>
                        <name>Commercial</name>
                    </license>
                </info>
                <!-- Support classpath or file absolute path here.
                1) classpath e.g: "classpath:/markdown.hbs", "classpath:/templates/hello.html"
                2) file e.g: "${basedir}/src/main/resources/markdown.hbs",
                    "${basedir}/src/main/resources/template/hello.html" -->
                <templatePath>${basedir}/templates/strapdown.html.hbs</templatePath>
                <outputPath>${basedir}/generated/document.html</outputPath>
                <swaggerDirectory>generated/swagger-ui</swaggerDirectory>
                <securityDefinitions>
                    <securityDefinition>
                        <name>basicAuth</name>
                        <type>basic</type>
                    </securityDefinition>
                </securityDefinitions>
            </apiSource>
        </apiSources>
    </configuration>
</plugin> 
........
```

You can download *.hbs template at this address:
https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-example

Execute `mvn swagger:generate`
JSon documentation will be generated at your project /generated/swagger/ directory.
Past it on this address :
http://editor.swagger.io

And generate what ever you want ( Server side or Client side API in your preferred technology )

Comment: This seems kind of uncomfortable, considering I have documented my whole API with `Swagger2` annotations.

Comment: @tgr the plugin fully supports Swagger2 annotations to a swagger.json

Answer (score 13):

I'm a little late here, but I just figured out that you can open your browser console and find the URL to the GET request that returns the JSON definition for your Swagger docs. The following technique worked for me when mapping my API to AWS API Gateway.

To do this:

1. Navigate to your Swagger docs endpoint
2. Open the browser console
3. Refresh the page
4. Navigate to the network tab and filter by XHR requests
5. Right click on the XHR request that ends in `?format=openapi`
6. You can now just copy and paste that into a new JSON file!

Comment: + you have to copy the Response body content of the XHR request, where the JSON is available

Comment: how can I do all that using java ??

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to get your swagger.json at

http://localhost:8080/api-docs

assuming your don't have kept the versioning as in the pet store sample application. In that case the URL would be:

http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs

Comment: this is the right answer! Just add /v2/api-docs after the path of the API and use `curl`: like `curl -k hxxps://domain.com/myapi/v2/api-docs`

Answer (score 3):

To get the api json definition for REST API, if swagger is configured properly. you can use directly swagger/docs/v1, this means the complete url will be, if version v1 (or just specify the version)

http://localhost:8080/swagger/docs/v1

Comment: Worked very good. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: This is simple and useful tip. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys @Hezron Naresh