# Swagger in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to add swagger in my **`Angularjs`** project

**OBJECTIVE**

I want to test my API via swagger by sending a payload and in return I will get response code 200.

I am following tutorials:

https://www.phpflow.com/jquery-plugin-2/how-to-integrate-swagger-with-angular/

http://orange-opensource.github.io/angular-swagger-ui/ (WORKING DEMO of TUTORIAL)

What I have done so far:

1. Added these two libraries in my project

   ```
   <script src="bower_components/angular-swagger-ui/dist/scripts/swagger-ui.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-swagger-ui/dist/css/swagger-ui.min.css">
   ```

**HTML**

```
<div >
        <h3 class="dispInline">Rest Json file:</h3>
        <form name="urlForm" ng-submit="urlForm.$valid&&(swaggerUrl=url)" class="form-inline dispInline">
            <input type="url" placeholder="swagger URL" class="form-control" id="url" method="post" name="url" ng-model="url" required style="width:400px">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">explore</button>
        </form>
        <div swagger-ui url="swaggerUrl" try-it="true" error-handler="myErrorHandler" transform-try-it="myTransform"></div>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.url = 'https://server.event.com/alert/event/1.0/eventpublicationmanagement_01/events';
// error management
$scope.myErrorHandler = function(data, status){
    alert('failed to load swagger: '+status);
    console.log(data);
};
// transform try it request
$scope.myTransform = function(request){
    request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer 123123123-1231-123-134313313c';
};
```

But when I click on explore, I get 405 error that method is not allowed. My method is **post** but browser is somehow sending **GET**. My token is also not sending in request. How can I solve that?

[image]

Also, I am confused because with working of swagger, My `API` is published on **`WSO2 API Store`** which contains a default swagger and my `API` swagger looks something like this:

[image]

If I shall call my API by clicking on **explore** button, will it show/return an option like API Store is showing? -> **/eventpublicationmanagement_01/events**

How will I set my JSON as well?

I am very confused. Some guidance and help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have Your own "swagger.json" file? What is Your goal? What do You want to achieve?

Comment: No I don't have any swagger.json file. I just wanna add swagger to test my API by sending a payload to it. I wanna add same like WSO2 API store manager have by deafult.

Comment: I am using a swagger in my project but I have backend (java) and frontend (AngularJS) and to do it, on backend site there was a need to configure Swagger in order to get a swagger.json which tells SwaggerUI how services looks like.

Comment: In my case I am using wso2 ESB.  Is it necessary to configure it via backend?

Comment: Yes. From client side You can import the file. But previously You need to have the file.

Comment: But my API is already performing some other functionality. 
How did you configure swagger via backend did you create an API in java for that?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-restful-api-documentation-with-swagger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Swagger You need a swagger.json file. More info You can find in the link: [How to generate swagger.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808417/how-to-generate-swagger-json)

Comment: Done and able to get swagger GUI. Thankyou so much but I still need a little help regarding to token because right now I have to enable my CORS extension in chrome for calling my API how can I pass token with that in angular js

Comment: This is what I am doing right now    
                $scope.url = $scope.swaggerUrl = 'https://my/api/json/url/EventPublicationManagement/1.0';
               // console.log( $scope.url)
                // error management
                $scope.myErrorHandler = function(message, code){
                    alert(swaggerTranslator.translate('error', {
                        code: code,
                        message: message
                    }));
                };

Comment: Yes but I am unable to call my swagger.json url with cors. If I enable cors with chrome extension then it works what should I do now?

Comment: Thanks alot... :)