# Is it possible to generate a swagger.yaml or swagger.json with a command?

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I have multiples comments above my routes and i would like to generate a swagger.yaml or swagger.json with my informations with a command. is it possible ?

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * paths:
 *  /v1/enterprises:
 *      get:
 *          tags:
 *              - Enterprises
 *          summary:
 *              List of all enterprises
 *          description:
 *              List of all enterprises
 *          responses:
 *              200:
 *              description: Returns all enterprises
 */
router.get('/', enterprises.index);
```

Comment: what about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41823385/9175097

Comment: It's done manually, right?

Comment: you can use curl